# RTOS Task Management

Tags: rtos, task-switching

If a task is attempting to surrender the processor, what steps does a real time operating system need to execute to ensure that another task has the opportunity to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread yielding CPU is a *scheduling event*;  all scheduling events cause the *scheduler* to run.